# How to send data from Android with 3G/UMTS to a PC

Tags: android, wifi, umts

I want to send/receive data (e.g. binary or strings) from my mobile Android device to a PC over a WiFi Router.

Is it the same way I send data over WiFi with a TCP socket connection?

So I send data out of my client (Android device) and listen at my server at the port I defined?

If I already programmed the WiFi TCP socket connection, do I have to add additional program code to send the data with 3G or UMTS if I disable WiFi?

Thanks!

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that there is no additional code necessary because the sockets are on a higher layer on the OSI-model than Wifi or 3G.